# select distinct containing multiple data in a single column

Tags: mysql

I am going with Mysql.  In my sales business I have multiple data inside of a single column.  My sellers database with tens of thousands of seller names is shown.

```
name                   products
Bucky White
Bucky White
Sara Cole
Ed Timothy
Bucky White
```

SELECT DISTINCT name FROM 'sellers'

ends giving the wrong answer:

```
name                   products
Bucky White
Bucky White
Sara Cole
Ed Timothy
Bucky White
```

when the answer I'm after is:

```
name                   products
Bucky White
Sara Cole
Ed Timothy
```

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by spaces at the beginning or end of the string.  So, try this:

```
select distinct trim(name)
from sellers
```

If not spaces, then there is often some other character.  I would recommend doing this to start:

```
select distinct length(name), concat('|', name, '|')
from sellers
```

This will let you see of other characters are at the beginning or end of the name.

Comment: It is not spaces, so I tried the second, I understand what you are doing in mysql.  The concat part does not work.